# Group list of strings with common prefixes

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

Suppose I have a list of strings `[city01, city01002, state02, state03, city04, statebg, countryqw, countrypo]`

How do I group them in a `dictionary` of `<string, List<Strings>>` like

```
city - [city01, city04, city01002]
state- [state02, state03, statebg]
country - [countrywq, countrypo]
```

If not code, can anyone please help with how to approach or proceed?

Comment: Why do you think the first group wouldn't be `city0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
 var input = new List<string>()
{ "city01", "city01002", "state02",
   "state03", "city04", "statebg", "countryqw", "countrypo" };

var output = input.GroupBy(c => string.Join("", c.TakeWhile(d => !char.IsDigit(d))
            .Take(4))).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in other answers you can use the GroupBy method from LINQ to create this grouping based on any condition you want. Before you can group your strings you need to know the conditions for how a string is grouped. It could be that it starts with one of a set of predefined prefixes, grouped by whats before the first digit or any random condition you can describe with code. In my code example the groupBy method calls another method for every string in your list and in that method you can place the code you need to group the strings as you want by returning the key to group the given string under. You can test this example online with dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UHNXvZ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> ungroupedList = new List<string>() {"city01", "city01002", "state02", "state03", "city04", "statebg", "countryqw", "countrypo", "theFirstTown"};
        var groupedStrings = ungroupedList.GroupBy(x => groupingCondition(x));
    
        foreach (var a in groupedStrings) {
            Console.WriteLine("key: " + a.Key);
            foreach (var b in a) {
                Console.WriteLine("value: " + b);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string groupingCondition(String s) {
        if(s.StartsWith("city") || s.EndsWith("Town"))
            return "city";
        if(s.StartsWith("country"))
            return "country";
        if(s.StartsWith("state"))
            return "state";
        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you have a list of references you are searching in the list:

```
    var list = new List<string>()
    { "city01", "city01002", "state02",
        "state03", "city04", "statebg", "countryqw", "countrypo" };

    var tofound = new List<string>() { "city", "state", "country" }; //references to found
    

    var result = new  Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    foreach (var f in tofound)
    {
        result.Add(f, list.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(f)));
    }
```

In the result, you have the dictionary wanted.   If no value are founded for a reference key, the value of key is null

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This answer has a combinatorial expansion and will fail if your original string set is large. For 65 words I gave up after running for a couple of hours.

Using some `IEnumerable` extension methods to find `Distinct` sets and to find all possible combinations of sets, you can generate a group of prefixes and then group the original strings by these.

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static bool IsDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
        var hs = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            if (!hs.Add(item))
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) => !items.Any();

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> start) {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> HelperCombinations(IEnumerable<T> items) {
            if (items.IsEmpty())
                yield return items;
            else {
                var head = items.First();
                var tail = items.Skip(1);
                foreach (var sequence in HelperCombinations(tail)) {
                    yield return sequence; // Without first
                    yield return sequence.Prepend(head);
                }
            }
        }

        return HelperCombinations(start).Skip(1); // don't return the empty set
    }
}

var keys = Enumerable.Range(0, src.Count - 1)
            .SelectMany(n1 => Enumerable.Range(n1 + 1, src.Count - n1 - 1).Select(n2 => new { n1, n2 }))
            .Select(n1n2 => new { s1 = src[n1n2.n1], s2 = src[n1n2.n2], Dist = src[n1n2.n1].TakeWhile((ch, n) => n < src[n1n2.n2].Length && ch == src[n1n2.n2][n]).Count() })
            .SelectMany(s1s2d => new[] { new { s = s1s2d.s1, s1s2d.Dist }, new { s = s1s2d.s2, s1s2d.Dist } })
            .Where(sd => sd.Dist > 0)
            .GroupBy(sd => sd.s.Substring(0, sd.Dist))
            .Select(sdg => sdg.Distinct())
            .AllCombinations()
            .Where(sdgc => sdgc.Sum(sdg => sdg.Count()) == src.Count)
            .Where(sdgc => sdgc.SelectMany(sdg => sdg.Select(sd => sd.s)).IsDistinct())
            .OrderByDescending(sdgc => sdgc.Sum(sdg => sdg.First().Dist)).First()
            .Select(sdg => sdg.First())
            .Select(sd => sd.s.Substring(0, sd.Dist))
            .ToList();

var groups = src.GroupBy(s => keys.First(k => s.StartsWith(k)));
```